# Call to ICorRuntimeHost::UnloadDomain method never returns

Tags: c++

In my C++ windows application I have been using ICorRuntimeHost::UnloadDomain method and it works fine most of the time but when I have four or more clients using the application the call to this method hangs. My code is written to handle any error returned from this method or exception but I do not get any error back but the call never returns. I am wondering if anyone has run into a similar issue and if they found the root cause & the fix for the issue.
Also when the call hangs it unloads nothing. The issue is seen only when I have multiple threads executing the same code but not when it is single threaded. The maximum number of threads used is 5. They all work on requests received from multiple clients and call the unload method for each request they work on. The issue is only seen when number of users is 4 or higher. Everything works fine as long as the number of users is under 4.

Comment: That is not unusual at all, you'll have to debug it.  Since you'll have trouble re-creating the issue on your own machine, ask your users to provide you with a minidump of the deadlocked process.  Which thread is in an non-alertable wait state and executing in that domain should be obvious from the stack traces.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I was able to find out the deadlocked thread and resolve the issue.